# Preprocessor directive for certain address space

Tags: c++, c, avr

Lets say I wanted to define a directive that could take an int8_t and store it to a specified memory location say 0x0071. How would I do this?

I know I could say

```
#define DDRA 0xAA
```

And that would make DDRA = 0xAA, but how do I make it so that typing

```
DDRA = 0xBB;
```

will write 0xBB in address location 0x0071?

Comment: `#define DDRA (*reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(0x71))`

Comment: And it will not make `DDRA = ` anything.

Comment: Why use a preprocessor directive instead of a static constant?

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages,  so make a choice about which language you are talking about as the answer is vastly different between the two languages.

Comment: In C, rather than this: `DDRA = 0xBB;` which does nothing but cause the compiler to output a error message, use this: `*(int8_t*)DDRA = 0xBB;` which will modify one byte of memory at 0xAA

Comment: where did `will write 0xBB in address location 0x0071?` come from?  did you actually mean address 0x0071 or did you actually mean address 0xAA?

Comment: I specified that I wanted to store it at that address location in the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AVR-GCC headers define I/O ports using the internal `_SFR_IO8` macro, e.g. in `<avr/iom328p.h>`:

```
#define PORTB _SFR_IO8(0x05)
```

This macro is defined in `<avr/srf_defs.h>` as:

```
#define _SFR_IO8(io_addr) _MMIO_BYTE((io_addr) + __SFR_OFFSET)
```

Which, in turn, is resolved by the `_MMIO_BYTE` macro in the same file:

```
#define _MMIO_BYTE(mem_addr) (*(volatile uint8_t *)(mem_addr))
```

The definition of `__SFR_OFFSET` is… a little obscure. It has to do with the 32-byte offset between the AVR I/O space and the start of memory.

TL;DR: `#define DDRA _SFR_IO8(0x71)`, but the standard headers for your part should be doing this already if it's actually a standard I/O port.

Comment: nowhere did the OP state that the underlying platform was a AVR

Comment: @user3629249 Actually, they did! They tagged the question as "avr".

Comment: Thank you duskwuff. The basic version of this would be to write

    #define DDRC (*(volatile uint8_t *)(0x71))

This answers the quesiton